# Get cover art from Google Play music

Tags: android, google-play, albumart

I know how to get album art when google play music is playing a local file.

Is there a way to get the cover when the music played is not from a device file ?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this? Also could you share your way of fetching cover art for local files? Thanks!

Comment: i have just added an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to get the cover art:
I'm listening to google play notifications via Android's NotificationListenerService and get the large icon:

```
Bitmap coverbitmap = ((Bitmap) extras.getParcelable(Notification.EXTRA_LARGE_ICON));
```

This (using the "extras" bundle of notifications) requires API Level 19.

Comment: What size is the image?  Also it appears this api was deprecated.